# Entries in /etc/crontab not getting called in Centos 6.x

Tags: centos, cron, logs

I created a dummy entry in `/etc/crontab`, but it doesn't get executed according to the cron log: `/var/log/cron`:

```
Feb  7 08:20:01 localhost CROND[22781]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 08:30:01 localhost CROND[23132]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 08:40:01 localhost CROND[23137]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 08:50:01 localhost CROND[23147]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 09:00:01 localhost CROND[23922]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 09:01:01 localhost CROND[23977]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  7 09:01:01 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[23977]: starting 0anacron
Feb  7 09:01:01 localhost run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[23986]: finished 0anacron
Feb  7 09:10:01 localhost CROND[24264]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Feb  7 09:20:01 localhost CROND[24295]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

`/etc/crontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed

05 20 * * * root /data/CENTRAL_BACKUP/xxx.sh
```

The OS is Centos.

Answer (score 2):

Your cron job is set to be executed at 20 hour 5 minutes (24 hour format). And the log you provide is from 9 a clock. So you should wait till 20h to see it in the log.

And do not enter leading zeroes, this is not good practice, make your record like:

```
5 20 * * * root /data/CENTRAL_BACKUP/xxx.sh
```